# Automatically detecting XML or plain text input with file and STDIN with Perl

Tags: perl, stdin, libxml2

What is the most Perly way to detect XML (using XML::LibXML / libxml2) or plain text input with Perl (5.18 or higher)?

I have a program that can accept plain text input or XML input, and the XML input can be in arbitrary encodings. Input is either from a file (ARGV) or STDIN. When only plain text is considered, the following code is sufficient:

```
local $/ = undef;
my $text = <> || die;
```

This will get the entire input file or STDIN as text, using default encoding settings.

When only XML is considered, the following code is usable (for a file):

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml = $parser->load_xml(location => $ARGV[0]);
```

But what is the best way to combine the two? I want libxml2 to take a first crack at the input, then fall back to plain text if it fails. If I pass IO => *STDIN directly, libxml2 will consume the input, which the program will need later if libxml2 determines that the input is not XML.

(Note: if libxml2 determines that the input is some kind of XML but malformed in some way, then the program should terminate instead of falling back.)

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~fitzner/File-LibMagic-0.96/LibMagic.pm

Comment: How can you know whether a file containing `<doc/>` is an XML file or a plain text file? It could be both.

Comment: nwellnhof, that is a good point. My response is that you design the code to answer the question one way or another. In particular: `<doc/> ` is an XML file because XML does not have to start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`: you can go right into the first element. You can also have a Byte Order Mark as the first character. The more general point is that I would like _libxml2 to take a first crack at the input, then fall back to plain text if (libxml2 parsing) fails_. Based on some tests, libxml2 will also accept whitespace before and after the root element.

Answer (score 0):

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $schema_file = 'test.xsd';
my $document    = 'test.xml';

my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $schema_file);

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($document); #Or handle STDIN

eval { $schema->validate($doc) };
if ($@){
    #file failed to validate, handle as text below
}
```

Alternatively you could use [Text::XML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::XML)'s `is_xml`, `is_well_formed_xml` methods and create conditionals based on those.

Comment: Sorry but not actually what I am looking for. I am not looking to validate the XML; I am looking to determine if the input is XML (in any encoding). For example, it could start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, or UTF-8 BOM 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF followed by <root/>, or UTF-16BE with or without BOM, or even EBCDIC. I want to deliver the bytes from STDIN directly to libxml2, but then if libxml2 says it's not XML, to keep the bytes to try to process the stream as plain text.